# can I call a function to set my USERNAME_FIELD = ''?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

can I call a function in  USERNAME_FIELD = '' to create an optional choice for login, using email or phone number? if yes how?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can

you can write special login function in your view and use query like this :

```
user = User.objects.filter(Q(email=value)|Q(username=value)).first()
login(request, user)
```

I use Q django db functions to complex query and I can use Or in my queries for example in up code I filter email equal by value or username equal by value so if uaer enter username or email I can find him

in other ways I can use two query but its not common
like this :

```
user_by_username=User.objects.filter(usernsme=value).first()
if user_by_username:
    login(request,user)
else:
    user_by_email=User.objects.filter(email=value).first()
    if user_by_email:
        login(request,user_by_email)
```

and default user model hasn't mobile field you can save mobile as username or create special usermodel
or create new model for your user profile

Comment: So what should I write in my username field if I want to use optional choice? @pouria farhadi

Comment: if you want optional username or email you can save email as username